# How Do I use C# System.Data.Common.DbBatch?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I feel like I'm missing something completely elementary here.  How do I use the C# [DbBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbbatch?view=net-6.0) class?  I'm working on optimizing a client's SQL commands and they use both Oracle and SQL Server.  This class looks to be a perfect batching candidate, but I'm having trouble just spinning up a simple instance to test some insert statements with for a performance test.  The MS documentation is pretty basic on this and I've been scouring the web for any help.  I saw [this](https://www.demo2s.com/csharp/csharp-dbbatch-tutorial-with-examples.html) page which just dumps a massive class with 0 explanation and uses their own NuGet package to do some black magic.  I'm just hoping someone can shed some light on this where I am failing to see how this is used.

`public abstract class DbBatch : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable` is the class.  In implementing my own class that inherits DbBatch, it looks like I have to pretty much write everything as DbBatch looks to be just a shell of a class.  I'm not really understanding how this class is helpful and would love to see an example before I go down the rabbit hole of implementing this class only to see negligible gains.

I am not asking for performance help with the client, I am asking strictly about DbBatch and nothing else.

Just trying to insert x number of records in a database using a unit test at the moment.  I've already got several methods built to test different ways of trying to batch using a simple query like `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@value1,@value2);`.  Nothing crazy at all.

Below is one of the unit tests I'm using for a performance test to be able to quickly run any/all of them to try out different scenarios.  This one doesn't have any batching and is closer to what the client is doing in their code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Insert_Individual_Loop_StoredProc()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
    {
        conn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++)
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("TEST_Insert", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestParam1", i));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed={sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```

Below is a unit test created to test the performance on the client's current inserts/updates records

```
[TestMethod]
public void Insert_Individual_Loop_DTE()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    DBFactory.SetDataProvider("System.Data.OleDb", true);
    IDbConnection conn = DBFactory.GetConnectionConfiguration.Config.Settings.ConnectionString);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++)
    {
        var query = CreateInsertCommand(i);
        DBFactory.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, CommandType.Text, query);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed={sw.Elapsed}");
}
```

I am trying several things other than just batching to optimize them, but they don't use any ORM, they just use queries written in code or in a lookup table.  They have asked me to add batching, and while I am testing batching I am not thinking this is going to magically fix all their issues.  I am just trying to implement a very simple DbBatch class to test alongside the other methods I'm trying to optimize them and it will most likely be a mix of several to get them from where they are to where they need to be.

Comment: `I'm working on optimizing a client's SQL commands` this feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that batching isn't going to help with. I'd suggest asking a new question, providing more context as to the problem you're actually facing, and maybe we'll be able to assist you.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current try? For me it's hard to answer because you are speaking about unit tests, where we generally mock this kind of stuff rather than executing it on the one hand and, on the other hand you are wondering about batch inserts. So this question is a bit vague.

Comment: There's several things on this single request asked of me, but they are currently updating thousands of records in a table using individual SQL commands and they would like batching to speed it up.  I'm also testing out using stored procedures to improve performance and want to be able to present SQL commands batched, stored procedures possibly batched, etc.  I'll be able to run several tests to determine which method provides the most benefit, I'm just trying to get the DbBatch class in play as it looks like it would be an easy lift with great benefits.

Comment: @Mr.Anderson then this is not a unit test, but a speed test. Which is okay, but you still need to share what you tried so we can look at your specific problem rather than implementing a feature for you from scratch.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just using unit tests as an easy place to call each performance test.

Comment: @IanKemp very valid point.  I'm trying different things to see which solves their issue.  They asked to add batching, but I've already found several other things that would optimize their performance.  I've done quite a bit of SQL optimizations over the years and DbBatch is a new API I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: @Mr.Anderson if you want to speed up operations on thousands of rows, store them to a staging/temp table with proper indexes and write a query that JOINs with the target and upserts. That will offer orders of magnitude better performance compared to sending 1 string with 1000 INSERTs or UPDATEs

Comment: @Mr.Anderson `solves their issue` what *is* the issue? Batching means instead of executing 1000 separate INSERTs to build one string with those 1000 inserts. A *really faster* option would be a single `INSERT` with 1000 rows values, ie `INSERT ... VALUES (@value1,@value2), (@value3,@value4),.....`

Comment: Even so, all rows will be fully logged. An even faster option is `SqlBulkCopy` which uses minimal logging, writing the entire data page to the transaction log instead of individual rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The issue is they are doing an export and inserting then updating thousands of rows one at a time.  If I could, I'd completely rewrite their entire db operation classes.  Just by calling the MS classes directly instead of their custom classes that call the MS classes, I've cut the time in half.  It's a massive project with hundreds of calls to a handful of methods and I'm trying to update those base methods to speed up all the operations.

Comment: My current problem is, how do I use the DbBatch class.  That's my issue.  I can and will figure out their performance issues as I have done with many clients in the past.  I think I made a very simple ask and would just like to have someone point me in a direction where I can see a very simple example of how DbBatch is used so I can see if it's worth all the hassle.

Comment: You *assume* the problem can be solved that way. AFAIK that class is only implented  by the open source MySqlConnector project (not Oracle's). I explained what the typical way is to perform bulk operations, which is orders of magnitude faster than batching *and* simpler.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is why I am writing a series of unit tests, so assumption is out of the picture and I can accurately determine which one is faster.  I assume nothing except that asking a simple question can net a simple answer which I see can no longer happen on SO.

Comment: Another option is to use table-valued parameters to pass values as a table to your stored procedure and update the target by JOINing with the TVP. This will be a lot faster than batching but not as fast as the staging table, because a TVP has no statistics - SQL Server doesn't know how many rows there will be in that table in future calls. Check [Table valued parameters in SQL Server calls](https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @Mr.Anderson unit tests don't remove assumptions. The behavior of SQL Server is documented and the features you ask are used for over 20 years. OK, TVPs for 18 years. ETL is a *very* mature discipline

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can figure out many different ways that are faster than what they are currently doing.  I've been programming for over 35 years, have been working with SQL for nearly 20 of those.  If I had a clean slate I would do things very different.  I'm trying to find something that can give improvements with minimal code change in a huge monolith.  I just would like to see DbBatch class.  That's all.

Comment: In that case why are you even looking at DbBatch? You *know* that batching just concatenates INSERT statements. You don't need a new class for that, and the method simply isn't listed in the docs. It appears in DbConnection but not SqlConnection. That means it's not implemented or only for internal use. EF Core uses MERGE with row values syntax to implement batching, it doesn't concatenate INSERTs

Comment: If you want to use batching, create the row values yourself, or use a statement generator. There are libraries that can do this. You don't need DbBatch

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, I've used them and even created batching myself.  I literally just want to see if DbBatch is worth it and after all of this, I really don't think it is.

Comment: If you want to see examples of DbBatch, [check the issue status](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28633). Only NpgSql and MySqlConnector have implementations. You can check MySqlConnector's [MySqlBatch example](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbatchtype/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cannot find the page now, but I saw somewhere that Oracle and MSSQL had implementations of it.  I've been looking this class up for 2 days and everywhere I look seems to turn up a dead end.  I'll continue trying other methods to optimize them and leave DbBatch alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [isn't finished yet](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/19) in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. The base types and methods are there but the SqlClient implementation hasn't been merged yet.

The following code prints `False`:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

var con = new SqlConnection();
Console.WriteLine($"Is batching supported? {con.CanCreateBatch}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The [Github feature issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28633) shows that only NpgSQL and MySqlConnector (the open source one, not Oracle's) have implemented this feature. Microsoft itself no longer maintains an Oracle client and Oracle's provider is closed-source.

ADO.NET and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient are separate project. In the .NET Core era, ADO.NET is built to serve all providers and doesn't give priority to SQL Server (although the same contributors may work in both projects). A missing implementation in SqlClient won't block the release of a feature in ADO.NET.

There are other features like the DI-friendly [DbDataSource](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2119) that have no native implementation in SqlClient yet.